# Database schema for passing requests to role based users

Tags: database-design

I am working on a Database schema where the scenario should be:

1. There are role based `User`s; `Role 1`, `Role 2`, `Role 3` and `Role 4`
2. There is a `Request` model (or class, or table)
3. User with role `Role 1` will create a new `Request`
4. This `Request` needs to be executed by a single `User` from each `Role`. Execution means passing on a `Request` from one `User` to an other and entering comments.
5. `Role 1` will decide which `User` from each `Role` will execute the `Request`
6. The workflow of execution will be predefined, for now suppose `Role 1` > `Role 2` > `Role 3` > `Role 4` and then again > `Role 1`. The workflow will be cyclic.
7. But a `User` associated with a particular `Role` to execute a `Request` may change in an other cycle
8. I need to track the history with who executed a `Request` with what comments
9. Workflow should be changeable

I don't know whether I am clearly able to explain my requirement or not. But will request you to try to understand and/or discuss this question with me and help creating me this schema.

The current Db schema which I am thinking of, but is not very useful and scalable:

**Request** table

```
- id
- name
- some_other_stuff
- currently_assigned_to
```

**Assignment** table

```
- id
- request_id
- role_1
- role_2
- role_3
- role_4
```

**Workflow** table

```
- id
- request_id
- executed_by
- comment
```

The `Assignment` table will handle which `User` has to execute the `Request` based on which `Role` they are assigned to. `Role 1` `User` will execute and the `Request` will be passed to `Role 2` `User` and further on.

The `Workflow` table will save the history.

Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OK - here's my first pass at answering your question.

If a user has role1 in a given assigment and can have another role in a different assigment, then my schema will have to change. If necessary, this can be looked at. I think that some of your requirements will require more than SQL to fulfill - you will probably have to start looking at triggers.

You haven't mentioned your RDBMS - my schema is for PostgreSQL. For example MySQL doesn't have the capabilities of PostgreSQL, but you can implement many things  triggers and stored procedures. I would **strongly** recommend PostgreSQL over MySQL if you're going for an Open Source database. Firebird is also a far more capable RDBMS than MySQL. CHECK CONSTRAINTs, REGEXes, CTEs and analytic functions - not implemented (or very poorly so - REGEXes) in MySQL, present in the others.

There are a couple of extra tables in my schema - let me know if this corresponds to your needs. I'm assuming that a request will be broken into assigments - no need to have 4 roles per assignment - the information on who performed each assignment will be in the workflow tables

You could eliminate the workflow table by putting a user_id there and a boolean for completed - maybe simpler? Though having a small assignment table and moving completed assignments to the workflow table might have  favourable performance impact.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS workflow;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assignment;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS request;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_user;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS role;
```

Remove the tables if they exist.

```
CREATE TABLE role  -- caution, may be a reserved word in some RDBMSs.
(
  role_id SERIAL CONSTRAINT role_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  role_name VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  role_description VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE my_user  -- user is a reserved word in PostgreSQL.
(
  user_id SERIAL  CONSTRAINT user_pk PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  user_name VARCHAR(25) CONSTRAINT user_name_nn NOT NULL,
  user_role INT,                   -- NOT NULL not necessary due to FK constraint 
  CONSTRAINT user_role_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_role)
      REFERENCES role (role_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE request
(
  request_id SERIAL CONSTRAINT request_pk PRIMARY KEY, 
  request_name VARCHAR(20) CONSTRAINT rq_name_nn NOT NULL, 
  request_user_id INT CONSTRAINT rq_user_nn NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT req_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (request_user_id)
      REFERENCES my_user (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


CREATE TABLE assignment
(
  assignment_id SERIAL CONSTRAINT assignment_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  assignment_req_id INT CONSTRAINT assgt_req_id_nn NOT NULL,
  assignment_role INT CONSTRAINT assgt_role_id_nn NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT asst_req_fk FOREIGN KEY (assignment_req_id)
      REFERENCES request (request_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);


CREATE TABLE workflow
(
  workflow_id SERIAL CONSTRAINT workflow_id PRIMARY KEY,
  workflow_req_id INT CONSTRAINT wkflw_req_id_nn NOT NULL,
  workflow_user_id INT CONSTRAINT wkflw_user_id_nn NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT wkflw_req_fk FOREIGN KEY (workflow_req_id)
     REFERENCES request (request_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT wkflw_user_fk FOREIGN KEY (workflow_user_id)
     REFERENCES my_user (user_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```